# UnicodeDecodeError on Import Packages statement in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: import, unicode, jupyter-notebook

I'm simply trying to import libraries, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and getting this **"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 3200: invalid start byte"** error.

I'm new to Jupyter Notebooks and wondering if I didn't set something up correctly. I'm attaching the full error message I'm getting.

Any advice would be GREATLY appreciated.
[Error Message Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqswl.png)

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error message as *text*.

Comment: Are you using a very old version of pandas/numpy/mpl? Or how did you installed them? The error seems related that your sources are not UTF-8. Maybe you cloned with git and your git option have automatic charset conversion because of an old project?